# BASH - Prompting for Answers

Tags: bash, prompt

I'm using the following as  base for asking my users for some input.

```
while true; do
    echo "Proceed (y/n)"
    read yn
    case $yn in
        [Nn]*) break;;
        [Yy]*)
            while true; do
                echo "name"
                read name

                echo "id"
                read id

                echo "email"
                read email

                echo "location"
                read -i "south" location

                while true; do
                    echo -e "\nIs the above correct ? (y/n)"
                    read res
                    case $res in
                        [Nn]* ) break 1;;
                        [Yy]* )
                            echo -e "\nHere we go."

                            break 3;;
                    esac
                done
            done;;
        *) echo "Please answer yes or no.";;
    esac
done
```

If they answer no to 'Is the above correct' they are taken back to the start of the questions.. that works fine but how do I prefill the answers with their previous answer ?

Currently when they back to the start the results are defaulted back to the original entries either blank or the default option.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would make more use of the `-i` option to prefill the input of the `read` command with the previously read value. The user can edit the value if they like. You can also use the `-p` option to add the prompt directly to the `read` command.

```
location=south
while true; do
    read -p "Proceed (y/n)" yn
    case $yn in
        [Nn]*) break;;
        [Yy]*)
            while true; do
                read -p "Name: " -i "$name" name
                read -p "ID: " -i "$id" id
                read -p "Email: " -i "$email" email
                read -p "Location: " -i "$location" location

                while true; do
                    read -p "Is the above correct ? (y/n)"res
                    case $res in
                        [Nn]* ) break 1;;
                        [Yy]* )
                            echo -e "\nHere we go."

                            break 3;;
                    esac
                done
            done;;
        *) echo "Please answer yes or no.";;
    esac
done
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've been using `echo` as that allows me to change the color of the prompt. Can that be done with `read -p`

Comment: This doesn't work for me. When I say no, no values are pre filled.

Comment: Which "no"? You have to answer yes to `Proceed` at least once.

Comment: After entering my details I get to 'Is the above correct' If I answer no then the questions repeat but my previous answers aren't shown.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what it is you are trying to do, that you want to preserve and display the last values the user entered before choosing "No" to "Is the above correct?", then what you need to do is simply test whether the variable has already been set, and if so, display the prompt with the original value, and if not, simply display the prompt.

This works simply for the first user, but from then on, you are responsible for making use of the variable values, as needed, and then *Unsetting the values* before you begin prompting the next person. You are using whether the variables are empty to determine to display the "Prompt only" and it the variables are filled, you display the "Prompt with previous answer".

There are a lot of ways to do this. The simplest based on your existing script would be something like:

```
name=
id=
email=
south=
location=
while true; do
    echo "Proceed (y/n)"
    read yn
    case $yn in
        [Nn]*) break;;
        [Yy]*)
            while true; do
                [ -n "$name" ] && echo "name: $name" || echo "name: "
                read name

                [ -n "$id"] && echo "id: $id" || echo "id: "
                read id

                [ -n "$email" ] && echo "email: $email" || echo "email: "
                read email

                [ -n "$location" ] && echo "location: $location" || echo "location: "
                read -i "south" location

                while true; do
                    echo -e "\nIs the above correct ? (y/n)"
                    read res
                    case $res in
                        [Nn]* ) break 1;;
                        [Yy]* )
                            echo -e "\nHere we go."
                            ## use vars and then unset for next person
                            break 3;;
                    esac
                done
            done;;
        *) echo "Please answer yes or no.";;
    esac
done
```

Look things over and let me know if I understood you correctly and whether you have any changes. I'm happy to help further.

Comment: I get errors when I run this .`syntax error near unexpected token `('
`                    echo -e "\nIs the above correct ? (y/n)"'`

Comment: Looks like a missing `"` in ` [ -n "$id]`

Comment: Oh.... duh..... Thanks fixing. (that will do it every time...) Also note, this is an example of how to output the old values, in practice they should be presented with the `'-i'` option to `read`.

Answer (score 0):

(OFF TOPIC: I would try to avoid the `break 3`.)
You can write a function `readDefault` with $1 the variable to display/read for the default value and the other parameters as an optional prompt.

```
readDefault() {
   varname=$1
   shift
   if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
      read -p "${varname} [${!varname}]: " userinput
   else
      read -p "$* [${!varname}]: " userinput
   fi
   printf -v ${varname} "%s" "${userinput:-${!varname}}"
}

# First time defaults outside loop
location="south"
while true; do
    echo "Proceed (y/n)"
    read yn
    case $yn in
        [Nn]*) break;;
        [Yy]*)
            while true; do
                readDefault name "What is your name"
                readDefault id
                readDefault email "Used for sending monthly reports"
                readDefault location

                while true; do
                    echo "Current values: ${name}, ${id}, ${email}, ${location}"
                    echo -e "\nIs the above correct ? (y/n)"
                    read res
                    case $res in
                        [Nn]* ) break 1;;
                        [Yy]* )
                            echo -e "\nHere we go."

                            break 3;;
                    esac
                done
            done;;
        *) echo "Please answer yes or no.";;
    esac
```